# Ajax: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have just started with ajax and followed some tutorial, I'm getting this error when im trying to run this html file and a linked JavaScript file,

I know browser can not make request to file// so I started http-server that is listening on port 8080 and given address of that file.
here is code in my javascript file:

Its just a simple ajax request and response model

```
function test() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    //when request is made you wanna do it with XMLHttpRequest method!
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log('xmlhhtprequest object was created')
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    console.log('activex object was created')
}

    //checking if request was successful
if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        console.log('request was successful')
} else {
     console.log('request was unsuccesful')
}

//when response is recieved 
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //checking for response is recieved
    if (httpRequest.readystate === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML 
 =    httpRequest.responseText;

    } else {
          console.log('Error Occured')
    }
}

//actually making request 
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://192.168.43.227:8080/Desktop/
simpleserver/test.txt', true);

httpRequest.send();
}
```

The HTML file:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="test()">Click me!</button>
<div id="result">Result</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have `web.config` file to manage server-side access?

Comment: No, i just downloaded http-server through npm install http-server -g

Answer (score 0):

Since its cross-origin access error, there is few plugin available in chrome to make cross domain request, preferably **Chrome CORS** plugin. Then use following command in command line to disable security for cross domain access in chrome.
Run following command under command prompt.

```
start chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Make sure all the chrome instance is closed before running this command. Once successfully run, you will see yellow strip under chrome browser.